# GatsbyJS Invariant Violation: Encountered an error trying to infer a GraphQL type

Tags: javascript, graphql, shopify, gatsby

Useful Links:

- [Retrieving metafields with the Storefront API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/custom-storefronts/storefront-api/guides/metafields)
- [Shopify GraphQL Admin API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/graphql-admin-api)
- [Shopify GraphQL Storefront API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/custom-storefronts/storefront-api/getting-started)

Recently Shopify released a way to [retrieving metafields with the Storefront API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/custom-storefronts/storefront-api/guides/metafields)
. 
In order to get read access to metafields from [Shopify GraphQL Storefront API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/custom-storefronts/storefront-api/getting-started) we have to whitelist metafields from [Shopify GraphQL Admin API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/graphql-admin-api).

I created 2 local plugins:

1. [`gatsby-source-shopify-metafields`](https://github.com/iamskok/gatsby-shopify-invariant-violation-example/tree/master/plugins/gatsby-source-shopify-metafields) which uses `graphql-request` to `updateMetafieldStorefrontVisibility` of the exact metafield on a product. To run `updateMetafieldStorefrontVisibility` mutation do `cd plugins/gatsby-source-shopify-metafields && node lib.js`.
2. [`gatsby-source-shopify`](https://github.com/iamskok/gatsby-shopify-invariant-violation-example/tree/master/plugins/gatsby-source-shopify) it's an updated version of the [`default gatsby-source-shopify`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-shopify/) plugin with edited `queries.js`, `nodes.js` and `gatsby-node.js` files to include newly avialable `metafields` field.

After running `updateMetafieldStorefrontVisibility` I was able to query product metafields using `curl`:

```sh
curl -X POST \
"https://shop-name.myshopify.com/api/graphql.json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/graphql" \
-H "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
-d '
query {
  productByHandle(handle: "nike-air-max-720") {
    metafield(namespace: "global", key: "free_shipping") {
      value
    }
  }
}
'
```

Response: `{"data":{"productByHandle":{"metafield":{"value":"true"}}}}`

To reproduce the error please clone **[this repo](https://github.com/iamskok/gatsby-shopify-invariant-violation-example)**

On `gatsby develop` I get `Invariant Violation: Encountered an error trying to infer a GraphQL type` error:

```sh
gatsby develop
success open and validate gatsby-configs — 0.004 s
success load plugins — 0.368 s
success onPreInit — 0.006 s
success initialize cache — 0.094 s
success copy gatsby files — 0.045 s
success onPreBootstrap — 0.006 s

gatsby-source-shopify/new-dev-sandbox starting to fetch data from Shopify

gatsby-source-shopify/new-dev-sandbox fetched and processed blogs: 274.471ms

gatsby-source-shopify/new-dev-sandbox fetched and processed policies: 278.416ms

gatsby-source-shopify/new-dev-sandbox fetched and processed productTypes: 406.051ms

gatsby-source-shopify/new-dev-sandbox fetched and processed articles: 641.547ms

gatsby-source-shopify/new-dev-sandbox fetched and processed collections: 754.319ms


gatsby-source-shopify/new-dev-sandbox fetched and processed products: 1832.663ms

gatsby-source-shopify/new-dev-sandbox finished fetching data from Shopify: 1848.663ms
success source and transform nodes — 1.903 s
warning Multiple node fields resolve to the same GraphQL field `ShopifyCollection.products` - [`products`, `products___NODE`]. Gatsby will use `products___NODE`.
warning Multiple node fields resolve to the same GraphQL field `ShopifyProduct.metafields` - [`metafields`, `metafields___NODE`]. Gatsby will use `metafields___NODE`.
error UNHANDLED REJECTION


  Error: Invariant Violation: Encountered an error trying to infer a GraphQL type for: `metafields___  NODE`. There is no corresponding node with the `id` field matching: "Shopify__ProductMetafield__und  efined,Shopify__ProductMetafield__undefined,Shopify__ProductMetafield__undefined,Shopify__ProductMe  tafield__undefined".

  - invariant.js:40 invariant
    [gatsby-shopify-invariant-violation-example]/[invariant]/invariant.js:40:15

  - add-inferred-fields.js:259 getFieldConfigFromFieldNameConvention
    [gatsby-shopify-invariant-violation-example]/[gatsby]/dist/schema/infer/add-inferred-fields.js:25    9:3

  - add-inferred-fields.js:161 getFieldConfig
    [gatsby-shopify-invariant-violation-example]/[gatsby]/dist/schema/infer/add-inferred-fields.js:16    1:19

  - add-inferred-fields.js:87 Object.keys.forEach.key
    [gatsby-shopify-invariant-violation-example]/[gatsby]/dist/schema/infer/add-inferred-fields.js:87    :25

  - Array.forEach

  - add-inferred-fields.js:74 addInferredFieldsImpl
    [gatsby-shopify-invariant-violation-example]/[gatsby]/dist/schema/infer/add-inferred-fields.js:74    :28

  - add-inferred-fields.js:38 addInferredFields
    [gatsby-shopify-invariant-violation-example]/[gatsby]/dist/schema/infer/add-inferred-fields.js:38    :3

  - index.js:98 addInferredType
    [gatsby-shopify-invariant-violation-example]/[gatsby]/dist/schema/infer/index.js:98:3

  - index.js:64 typesToInfer.map.typeComposer
    [gatsby-shopify-invariant-violation-example]/[gatsby]/dist/schema/infer/index.js:64:43

  - Array.map

  - index.js:64 addInferredTypes
    [gatsby-shopify-invariant-violation-example]/[gatsby]/dist/schema/infer/index.js:64:23

  - schema.js:140
    [gatsby-shopify-invariant-violation-example]/[gatsby]/dist/schema/schema.js:140:11

  - Generator.next
```

#### Environment

- gatsby `v2.5.2`
- node `v11.14.0`

#### File contents

`gatsby-config.js`:

```js
require('dotenv').config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`
});

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-shopify',
      options: {
        shopName: `${process.env.SHOPIFY_SHOP_NAME}`,
        accessToken: `${process.env.SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
        verbose: true
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
}
```

I'm expecting to get clean build, instead, I get `Invariant Violation: Encountered an error trying to infer a GraphQL type`

Comment: This is a pretty common error message I’ve seen when using other GraphQL endpoint plugins with Gatsby, ex. the with WordPress. Usually it means you are getting something like `false` back from the API when you actually need `null`, and/or or you built the Gatsby site in one environment that assumed some kind of data would be present and now on a new Shopify site that data isn’t there yet. In this case, maybe no “Shopify__ProductMetafields” yet? What are you seeing in the GraphiQL interface? (http://localhost:8000/___graphql)

Answer (score 19):

Run `gatsby clean`.
This is a node reference error in a cached file.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem:
[image]

To solve it, I did `npm install gatsby-source-shopify`

Answer (score 0):

***just run "gatsby clean" to delete the cache file***

Comment: Removing the `.cache` folder solved this problem for me.

Comment: But we don't want to remove the .cache each build?